# How to insert HTML code dynamically?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

There's 2 types (Individual and Corporation). I managed to do the code for Individual, but now I want to do the same for Corporation.

[image]

So I tried to use

```
<%
    for(int k=0;k<clientTypes.length;k++) {
%>
```

on the top to make EXACTLY the same thing as in Individual.

My problem is that ids `dates` and `month-year` **do not work in my JavaScript** when in Corporation. That makes sense because I cannot repeat ids (right?). So how do I add this dynamically? clientTypes can be extended.

```
<div class="row types" style="margin-top: 10px;">
    <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-justified">
        <%
            String[] clientTypes = {"Individual","Corporation"};

            for(int k=0;k<clientTypes.length;k++) {
        %>
        <li><a data-toggle="tab" id="typeTab" name="type" href="#<%=clientTypes[k]%>"><%=clientTypes[k]%></a></li>
        <%
            }
        %>
    </ul>
</div>
    <div class="row" style="margin-top: 30px;">
    <div class="tab-content">
        <%
            for(int k=0;k<clientTypes.length;k++) {
        %>
        <div id="<%=clientTypes[k]%>" class="tab-pane fade in active">
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <div class="row">
                    <%
                        String initialDayEnd = session.getAttribute("initialDayEnd").toString();
                        String finalDayEnd = session.getAttribute("finalDayEnd").toString();

                        DateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy", Locale.US);

                        Calendar beginCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();
                        Calendar finishCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();

                        try {
                            beginCalendar.setTime(format.parse(initialDayEnd));
                            finishCalendar.setTime(format.parse(finalDayEnd));
                        } catch (ParseException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                        List<String> dateList = new ArrayList<String>();
                        List<String> dateListMonthYear = new ArrayList<String>();
                        String[] dateSplitted;
                        while (beginCalendar.before(finishCalendar)) {
                            // add one month to date per loop
                            String date = format.format(beginCalendar.getTime()).toUpperCase();
                            System.out.println(date);
                            beginCalendar.add(Calendar.MONTH, 1);
                            dateSplitted = date.split("/");
                            dateList.add(dateSplitted[0] + "/" + dateSplitted[1] + "/" + dateSplitted[2]);
                            dateListMonthYear.add(dateSplitted[1] + "/" + dateSplitted[2]);

                        }
                    %>
                        <label>Date:</label>
                        <select id="dates" name="dates">
                            <%
                                for (int i=0;i<dateList.size();i++) {
                            %>
                            <option value="<%=dateList.get(i)%>"><%=dateListMonthYear.get(i)%></option>
                            <%
                                }
                            %>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                <div class="row" style="margin-top: 20px">
                    <h1 id="month-year"></h1>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <label>Repeat For All:</label>
                <input class="inline-block text-center" type="number" id="repeatForAll" value="0">
            </div>
        </div>
        <%
            }
        %>
    </div>
    </div>
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
  $('#dates').change(DatesChanged);
    DatesChanged();

   function DatesChanged() {
       var date = $('#dates').val();
       var splitDate = date.split("/");
       day = splitDate[0];
       month = splitDate[1];
       year = splitDate[2];
       var maxDays = daysInMonth(month, year);
       var array = CreateJSONArray(maxDays, date);
   }
function DisplayTable(data) {

        //heading
        document.getElementById("month-year").innerHTML = data[0].monthName + ", " + data[0].year;

        //Table
        $('#dayTableBody').empty();
       $.each(data, function(key,value) {
           data += '<tr align="center">';
           data += '<td>' + value.dayNumber + '<input type="hidden" name="dayNumber" value="'+value.dayNumber +'">' + '</td>';
           data += '<td>' + value.dayName + '</td>';
           data += '<td>' + '<input class="text-center" type="number" value="0" id="numberOfClients" name="amountOfClients"> ' + '</td>';
           data += '</tr>';
       });
       $('#dayTableBody').append(data);

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use id="dates-<%=clientTypes[k]%>" and id="month-year-<%=clientTypes[k]%>"

In the javascript, use class instead of id.

```html
<select id="dates" name="dates" class="dates">
```

and in the javascript selector, use

```
$('.dates')
```

instead of

```
$('#dates')
```

Comment: and how do I do this: ` document.getElementById("month-year").innerHTML = data[0].monthName + ", " + data[0].year;` ?

Comment: You can use document.getElementsByClassName() instead.  This returns you an array on which you can do the operations for each result in the array.

Comment: So do I use id=dates or id="dates-<%=clientTypes[k]%>"??

Comment: You can use id="dates-<%=clientTypes[k]%>" to keep it syntactically correct. And, use the class to refer to them instead of id, in all places you want to refer them.

Comment: my javascript still not working when I'm Corporation tab.

Comment: Paste the result of view source of your page and the latest java script

Answer (score 0):

```
function display(){

var html = "<table id='mytable' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='0'>";
        for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) 
            {
                var k=i+1;
            html+="<tr>";
            html+="<td>"+" "+k+". "+list[i]+"</td>";
            html+="<td id='btns'> <input type='button' value='edit' class='edit-btn' onclick='editrow(this);'> ";
            html+="</td>";
            html+="</tr>";
                k=0;
            }
        html+="</table>";
        document.getElementById("lists").innerHTML = html;
```

}

i have made this function in **javascript**, which create table **dynamically** with **2 columns** in it
by this way u can also add anything u want in your **html code**

Comment: what is `list`?

Comment: list is name of my array in which my values are stored

Comment: var list=["abc","efg"]

Comment: you are crazy man. There must be a simpler way to do this. I will not change all my code.